# yield and provide() inside template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could anyone give clear explanation on how `provide()` works inside the view ? I have read official documentation but what really bothers me is this, if I define in the beginning of a template

```
<% provide(:title, 'Help') %>
```

and then later I have this line of code

```
<%= yield :title %>
```

what really happens in the background ? I know that yield is supposed to call code block. What would be code block in this context?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`provide` stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. In this case, 'Help' in the symbol :title. The provide is enclosed in `<% %>` to indicate it is executing this code and not printing out in the view.

`yield` in this case just spits that block back out. The yield is enclosed in `<%= %>` to indicate it is being printed out into the view.

Think of it as setting a variable and printing out a variable.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide
for more information. Note that `provide` is really a wrapper for `content_for` so that's where the good stuff is in that link.