# Michael Hartl's rails tutorial chapter 3, Error in rspec when

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am newbie to Ruby on rails. currently using maverick's 10.9.3, Rails 4. I am getting the following error when I try to run the rspec command.

here is the error that i get:

```
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:35 # PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:24 # PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:11 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
```

my Gemfile includes:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.14.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc'
end
```

also my pages_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end


    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end
  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
    end
  end
end
```

Controller code from the comment below:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def contact
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Comment: Michael's tutorial is the most validated ever :) Anyway.. one more thing which I found very useful is `gem launchy`. Get it and you can call `save_and_open_page` after `visit` to check how the page looks like.

Comment: actual controller code is as follows: class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def contact
  end
  
  def about
  end
end  and full error that i get is Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:33 # PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:22 # PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:11 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

Comment: <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Ruby On rails Tutorial sample App | about</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>About</h1>
  <p>
   This is the home page <a><href="railstutorial.org/">Ruby on rails tutorial</a>sample application.
  </p>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Please edit the question with the controller code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the documentation:
https://relishapp.com/rspec

Comment: i read the documentation and ran the gem install rspec-rails, installed the gems with bundle install and followed the direction but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as a lower case "a" for about vs About?

Your test is looking for the string "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About" and the code is producing "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | about".  As far as I know, rspec is case sensitive.

The other thing I have seen is having to set :visible to false for testing titles.

Comment: fixed that and i still get the following error for home, contact and about. rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:11 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

Comment: You fixed which?  The case or the :visble

Comment: I fixed the case sensitive string in the content. i did not understand what i should do for the :visible = false for testing titles.

Comment: Try adding ", :visible => false" after you string you are trying  to match.

Comment: @SinaR. Did this work for you?  If not, can you share a git repo so we can see the code?

Answer (score 0):

You may also come across this mistake 
[Ruby on Rail Michael Hartl's Chapter 3 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165106/ruby-on-rail-michael-hartls-chapter-3-error). You may be having this error as caught by the built-in test suite of Rails (which at the time of this writing is 'rails-controller-testing' - '1.0.2', 'minitest' - '5.10.3', 'minitest-reporters' - '1.1.14')

I advise you follow Michael Hartl's Gemfiles when reading his book to learn Rails.

> `provide` stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. In this case, 'Help' in the symbol :title. The provide is enclosed in `<% %>` to indicate it is executing this code and not printing out in the view.
>
> `yield` in this case just spits that block back out. The yield is enclosed in `<%= %>` to indicate it is being printed out into the view.
>
> Think of it as setting a variable and printing out a variable.
>
> See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide for more information. Note that provide is really a wrapper for content_for so that's where the good stuff is in that link.

This is taken from this StackOverflow article: [yield and provide() inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457985/yield-and-provide-inside-template)