# Ruby on Rail Michael Hartl's Chapter 3 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this error I keep getting in the Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial. Yes i did google this question and saw it was answered a couple times. I tried the solutions offered and they did not fix the problem. Here is the error:

```
ec2-user:~/environment/sample_app (static-pages) $ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 16202
Run options: --seed 53019

# Running:

F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about [/home/ec2-


user/environment/sample_app/test/controllers/
static_pages_controller_test.rb:20]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "title", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:17

F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home [/home/ec2-
user/environment/sample_app/test/controllers/
static_pages_controller_test.rb:8]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "title", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5

F

Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help [/home/ec2-
user/environment/sample_app/test/controllers/
static_pages_controller_test.rb:14]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "title", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:11



Finished in 0.171213s, 17.5220 runs/s, 35.0441 assertions/s.
3 runs, 6 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

So there's a miscommuinication from what it's trying to display and what the input is. I understand that part. But literally my code reads that it should work. I copied exactly from the book..

Here is my code for the static_pages_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

test "should get home" do
get static_pages_home_url
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App."
end

test "should get help" do
get static_pages_help_url
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App."
end

test "should get about" do
get static_pages_about_url
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App."
end


end
```

Here's my code for applications.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I'm so confused why this is not working. One answer from another post suggested that it had to do with something that Help doesn't have html.. but mine does. Anyone see what's going on here. I'm using cloud9 IDE.

Thanks,
Ben

EDIT 1: Update

Here's my home, help, and about html code. Home:

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>

<h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>This is the home page for the
<a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>
sample application
</p>
```

Help:

```
<% provide(:title, "Help") %>
<h1>Help</h1>

<p>
Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the
<a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help section</a>.
To get help on this sample app, see the
<a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book"><em>Ruby on Rails Tutorial</em>
book</a>.
</p>
```

About:

```
<% provide(:title, "About") %>

<h1>About</h1>

<p>
The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/"><em>Ruby on Rails
Tutorial</em></a> is a
<a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/book">book</a> and
<a href="http://screencasts.railstutorial.org/">screencast series</a>
to teach web development with
<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>.
This is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

To answer the questions below, this code isn't pushed to the repo yet. I'm hosting it locally (and testing it) before i post it. When i look at it in the local browser, the pages work, but the title (the tab at the top of the browser) is not populated. So it's clear the title function is not working.

Upadate 2: Added routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'static_pages#home'
get 'static_pages/home'
get 'static_pages/help'
get 'static_pages/about'
get 'static_pages/contact'

# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

# root 'application#hello'

end
```

Comment: Can you link to an updated repository?

Comment: What title does the browser show when you browse any of these pages? Also, it would be helpful if you can share your home.html.erb code.

Comment: @SagarPandya and Manoj Monga, please see EDIT 1 with more information and questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while studying Rails, but I found the answer in another StackOverflow article.

> `provide` stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. In this case, 'Help' in the symbol :title. The provide is enclosed in `<% %>` to indicate it is executing this code and not printing out in the view.
>
> `yield` in this case just spits that block back out. The yield is enclosed in `<%= %>` to indicate it is being printed out into the view.
>
> Think of it as setting a variable and printing out a variable.
>
> See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide for more information. Note that provide is really a wrapper for content_for so that's where the good stuff is in that link.

This is taken from this StackOverflow article: [yield and provide() inside template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457985/yield-and-provide-inside-template)