# How to make the | disappear from <%= #{@title} | " default title %> if there's no title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the Michael Hartl tutorial and came across a section that involves titles. At the time when I was on this section, an 'experienced' ruby dude told me that I could get rid of the provide functions and instead add a `@title` to make it easier. So on the line (off the top of my head since I'm currently at work) is:

```
<%= "#{@title} | " Default title %>
```

and on his website he built, he showed me that if there is no `@title`, it goes from `Home | Default title` to `Default title`. But when I delete the `@title` for the page, it still says `| Default title`.

How do I get rid of the `|` when there's no title?

I've attempted at making a helper using the if/else method thing, but since I'm pretty new at rails, I think I either butchered it, or going about the process the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want either `Title | Default title` or `Default title` you can do something like this:

```
<%= (@title ? "#{@title} | " : "") + "Default title" %>
```

If you want either `Title` or `Default title` you can do something like this:

```
<%= @title || "Default title" %>
```

If `@title` can be an empty string (but you would want to treat an empty string like a `nil`) replace `@title` with `@title.presence`:

```
<%= (@title.present? ? "#{@title} | " : "") + "Default title" %>
```

Or:

```
<%= @title.presence || "Default title" %>
```

Comment: so by using: <%= (@title ? "#{@title} | " : "") + "Default title" %> if there is no title, then it will use "Default Title" but if there is a title, it will use "Title | Default title"?

Comment: if you dont mind me asking, whats the "@title ?" mean? and also, does the "(: "")" mean that if the title is there, the "Default title" will go in the quotes?

Comment: @Curtis - for your first question - yes. the form `x ? y : z` is called [ternary operator](http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/ruby/ternary-operator). It is shorthand for `if x then y else z`

Comment: awesome! Makes sense. So does the blank quotes mean "if not y, z is blank"?

Comment: the empty quotes are simply an empty string - if `@title` is not present put an empty string instead of `"#{@title} | "`...

Comment: Gotcha. Last question: is the provide function better to use like the above commenter said? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Curtis - I'm not really familiar with it (it is a shame that Moahamad did not provide a link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457985/yield-and-provide-inside-template) I think you can read about it and see if it fits you

Answer (score 0):

Here's how. But I think doing this is a bad idea. `provide` is a much cleaner way of setting the title. So why not stick with it? You should move logic away from the view, and not into it.

```
<title>
  <% if @title %>
    <%= @title %>
  <% else %>
    "Default Title"
  <% end %>
</title>
```

More condensed:

```
<title>
  <%= @title || "Default Title" %>
</title>
```

Comment: Why is provide better? The below comment seems like it's easier to perform, and keeps everything cleaner instead of adding the provide on multiple pages

Comment: @Curtis Your solution is simpler if you have one page. It's not if you have multiple pages, and/or multiple layouts. You'll be polluting your views with an `@title` instance variable all over the place, and if you want to make a change, you must remember to do so in several places. Provides encapsulates the behaviour in one place. It gives you a clean and consistent way that works across layouts and templates. It exists for a reason. Trust me, not everything simpler is better. In this case its not, and its not recommended.

Comment: @Curtis also, you really should not be setting instance variables in your views, full stop.