# Rails <%provide%> more than one variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to provide more than one variable to the application layout with the <%provide(:var, "text)%> method? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to have two provide arguments, but there is a simple, if unsightly, solution:

```
<%provide(:var, "value)%>
<%provide(:var2, "value2")%>
```

Comment: You can check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457985/yield-and-provide-inside-template) link too

Answer (score 0):

If you want `:var` to have multiple values appended to it then, as per the explanation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for), you should be using **content_for**. It says:

> By default, content_for :thing appends whatever you put in your block
>   to the previous value of :thing.